# Export data to excel using queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, maatwebsite-excel

Hello I am trying to export excel file using laravel queue. I have integrated maatwebsite for the same.

### Here is what I have done so far

### Controller

```
public function export()
{
    $this->dispatch(new ExportDistributorJob([]));
    Session::flash('success','Data is being exported to excel file.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

### Job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use App\Model\Products;
use Excel;

class ExportDistributorJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(array $request)
    {
        $this->queue = 'default'; 
        $this->data = $request;
    }

    public function handle()
    {   
        $data = array(
                       'Name' => 'John', 
                       'City' => 'Washington'
                    );

        return Excel::create('invoice', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
        })->download('xlsx');

    }
} 

?>
```

When I execute the program. It stores data in jobs table and attempts 3 times to execute after that gets

> MaxAttemptsExceededException error.

I am not able to export data to excel file using queue.

```
 QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Any help would be appreciated.
 Thanks.

Comment: Your job is generating an error, after three times it will fail.
Read https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/collection.html here you can view how to export an collection.

You can also use the excel queue https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/queued.html

Comment: @ThijsBouwes It attempts to execute 3 times but why doens't export data to csv? If I change QUEUE_DRIVER to sync it works well.

Comment: Can you provide the log or exception?

Comment: After three time execution log shows error -
App\Jobs\ExportDistributorJob has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.

Comment: What version of the package are using?

Comment: It's maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0 and laravel version is 5.6

Comment: Based on the syntax i think you are using 2.1.0, can you try to replace `->download('xlsx')` to `->store('xlsx')` see https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/export/store.html for more info.

Comment: I changed it to store but nothing get change.

Comment: Do you find any luck for this problem ? job executing, performing insert update work but excel not downloading

Answer (score 0):

The `Excel` class is imported incorrectly from the package namespace.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
```

Also `ExportDistributorJob::handle` method is returning a [HTTP response and terminates the script](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/v2.1.0/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Writers/LaravelExcelWriter.php#L341)

In the context of a job, this is wreckless as it ends the job abruptly. You should instead [store the spreadsheet](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/v2.1.0/docs/export/store.md#normal-export-to-custom-storage-path).

```
public function handle()
{   
    $data = array(
                   'Name' => 'John', 
                   'City' => 'Washington'
                );

    return Excel::create('invoice', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data) {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->store('xlsx', storage_path('excel/exports'));

}
```